# Calculate quarterly values from an array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have a javascript array of 12 values, each number represents a  month.
The array is already sorted by months  ( *format ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', …, 'Dec']* ):

```
var revenue = [207485.19, 273455.34, 343804.25, 290400.2, 330941.67, 225798.4, 295580.96, 189529.26, 258365.37, 240740.14, 202847.97, 0]
```

The goal is to dynamically sum all the number by quarters and get the following output:

```
var revenue = [824744.78, 847140.27, 743475.59, 576379.85]
```

Below is what I started doing, but got stuck inside the if statements

```
const result = revenue.reduce((a, b, i) => {
 var initialQuarterIndex  = 0;
 var quarterIndex = Math.floor(i/3);
 if(quarterIndex === initialQuarterIndex ) {
   // do something here
 } else {
   // do something here
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) array into quarters and then calculate sum of each quarter using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Try this:

```js
let revenue = [207485.19, 273455.34, 343804.25, 290400.2, 330941.67, 225798.4, 295580.96, 189529.26, 258365.37, 240740.14, 202847.97, 0];
let res = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
  let quarter = revenue.splice(0, 3);//splice in quarters
  let sum = quarter.reduce((v1, v2) => {
    return v1 + v2;
  })//calculate sum
  res.push(sum);
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reduce()` and only add to the current value if you're on a current quarter, if you're on a new quarter (`i % 3 === 0`) then you can add the current value as a new quarter (ie new element) which will then be added to later:

```js
const revenue = [207485.19, 273455.34, 343804.25, 290400.2, 330941.67, 225798.4, 295580.96, 189529.26, 258365.37, 240740.14, 202847.97, 0];

const res = revenue.reduce((acc, n, i) => {
  const curr = acc.pop();
  return i && i % 3 === 0 ? [...acc, curr, n] : [...acc, curr+n]
}, [0]);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also do it with a for loop:

```js
var revenue = [207485.19, 273455.34, 343804.25, 290400.2, 330941.67, 225798.4, 295580.96, 189529.26, 258365.37, 240740.14, 202847.97, 0]

var result = []; 
let sum = 0;

for( let i=0; i<revenue.length; i++) {
  sum += revenue[i];
  if( (i+1) % 3 === 0 ) {
    result.push(sum);
    sum = 0;
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce` to loop through and use `Math.floor(i/3)` to split the quarter data.

```js
var revenue = [207485.19, 273455.34, 343804.25, 290400.2, 330941.67, 225798.4, 295580.96, 189529.26, 258365.37, 240740.14, 202847.97, 0];

let out = revenue.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
 let index = Math.floor(i/3)
 acc[index] = acc[index] + curr;
 return acc
}, Array(4).fill(0));

console.log(out)
```

OR one-liner solution

```
let out = revenue.reduce((acc, curr, i) => (acc[Math.floor(i/3)] +=  curr, acc), Array(4).fill(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with Array#reduce, Array#fill, Array#map

1. Create an empty array with a length equal to 4 (quarters)
2. Fill the array with `undefined` (otherwise `.map` won't work)
3. `.map` through your array and generate the indexes to calculate each quarter ( = 3, 6, 9, 12)
4. `.map` through the generated indexes and calculate the sum of the slices ( = 0 to 2, 3 to 5, 6 to 8, 9 to 11 )

```js
var revenue = [207485.19, 273455.34, 343804.25, 290400.2, 330941.67, 225798.4, 295580.96, 189529.26, 258365.37, 240740.14, 202847.97, 0];

const sum = (a) => a.reduce((acc, cur)=>acc + cur);

const groupsOf = 4;

const res = (new Array(groupsOf))
.fill(undefined)
.map((_, i) => (i+1) * revenue.length / groupsOf)
.map((offset, i, arr) => sum(revenue.slice(arr[i-1] || 0, offset)));

console.log(res);
```